# MVC Json Parsing - Swift

Tags: json, swift

I get json output from the MVC project. You can see this output in the image below. But I cannot draw this output on the swift side. For example, I sent the value 6 to the id parameter and got the output in postman. Likewise, how can I pull this data on the swift side?

[image]

```
 @objc func gorselCEK(){

     let url = URL(string: ".../MobilService/KategoriGorsel/")!
      var request = URLRequest(url: url)

     request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     request.httpMethod = "POST"

     let postString = "id=\(6)"
     request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                              guard let data = data else {
                                  return
                              }
        do {
           let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
             if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String],
                           let sifre = json[""] {
//Doesn't go in here
                                                                     }

                              } catch let parseError {
                                  print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
                                  let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                                  print("raw response: \(responseString)")
                              }
                          }
                          task.resume()
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the postman, it is GET request and in Swift, you're trying to make a POST request.

**Change request method to GET**

```
 request.httpMethod = "GET"
```

**Update URL with QueryItems**

```
 var urlComponent = URLComponents(string:".../MobilService/KategoriGorsel/")!

 url.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "6")
 ]

//Request
  var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponent.url)
  request.httpMethod = "GET"
```

*No need to set httpBody*

Comment: Error: Value of type 'URL' has no member 'queryItems'

Comment: Change let url = URL(string: ".../MobilService/KategoriGorsel/")! to 
var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: ".../MobilService/KategoriGorsel/")! Then take urlComponent.url